# why "else" statement doesn't work in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I create a button from movieClip if I click, the target will move to the next frame. if clicked again the target will return to the previous frame.

for the "IF" statement successfully executed, but for "else" the code doesn't work.

what's wrong with my code?

```
btn1.stop(); //stop the movieclip frame
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
function clicked(e: MouseEvent): void {
    var namebtn:String = e.currentTarget.name;
    if (namebtn == "btn1"){
      e.currentTarget.nextFrame();
    } else {
      e.currentTarget.prevFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it is the same button so the condition is always **true**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the moviclip instance name and that's why only if statement worked
You can try this

```
btn1.stop(); //stop the movieclip frame
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked);
function clicked(e: MouseEvent): void {
    if (btn1.currentFrame == 1){
      e.currentTarget.nextFrame();
    } elseif(btn1.currentFrame == 2) {
      e.currentTarget.prevFrame();
    }
}
```